# Is there some known problem that reflects the legitimacy of asking why infinitely many times?

Tags: epistemology

When I was a kid, I remind that I had a strange type of game - I was mostly concerned of annoying other persons. Whenever they assumed something, I asked why, and then when they aswered, I asked why again, and then I kept asking why until the person was annoyed. There was a point where the person could not provide an answer to the why's, I always wondered if our knowledge behaves this way: This way of having an infinite series of why's and at some point, a nullity of answers.

So, is this infinity of questions a problem somehow? Have someone thought about it?

Comment: I highly recommend Lewis Carroll's [What the Tortoise Said to Achilles](http://www.ditext.com/carroll/tortoise.html). It's a charming exposition in the form of a dialogue about how this infinite regress problem relates to the fundamental unprovability of modus ponens.

Comment: There are two possible meanings in the question "Why?": 1. "Why should I believe that? What are the reasons to assume it?" and 2. "Why is it this way? What caused it?" Usually a child that wants to annoy does not differentiate the both. But answering your question would be easier if you did.

Comment: Did you know that "because!" as a response to why can also be infinite? Why does not imply only logical answers or knowledge, why also implies will of others, desires and so no. Moreover >!< very deep down the infinite cycle "why" meets almighty "HOW". How would you make the world? It is this marriage of infinite why's and how's that makes finity.

Comment: I would answer, but cannot as my answer in infinitely long......

Answer (score 3):

This is related to Agrippa's trilemma which is a traditional problem in epistemology.
The trilemma goes like this: every piece of knowledge needs to be justified by another piece of knowledge. If knowledge is possible at all:

- either you need an infinite serie of true propositions to justify any piece of knowledge, which seems out of reach for anyone
- either you have to stop somewhere and accept that some pieces of knowledge need not be justified, but then you're a dogmatist
- either you fall back at one point on the very proposition you were trying to justify, but then your justification is circular

Otherwise you have to be skeptic about the possibility of knowledge.

Non skeptic answers to the trilemma involve accepting one of these three possibilities, respectively:

- infinitism (rarely defended),
- foundationalism, sometimes associated with empiricism, where experience is at the root of knowledge, but also with rationalism, where reason and intuition play the foundational role, and
- coherentism, often associated with idealism, where everything reduces to the mental, and knowing Basically equates having a coherent belief system.

See also: http://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regress_argument

Comment: Mental is not belief system. Mental is vision. Important distinction if not opposite.

Comment: I didn't say the mental is a belief system, but knowledge is.

Comment: Hm, i doubt that. Knowledge is knowledge. It is rare yes and contaminated by lots of stuff yes (also beliefs), but nevertheless it is a real thing. Conception of knowledge is there and you can not substitute it with belief.Belief is wide and knowledge rare -- yes.

Comment: I didn't say knowledge is *nothing but* a belief system, my answer only implies that, according to one position (one I don't personnaly endorse, coherentism), knowledge is a specific type of belief system (a coherent one). You seem to overinterpret my answer.